# How do I minimize the critical request depth for initial navigation?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, critical-css

I was working on a similar issue for woff2 file type and made it successfully.

Thing is, the woff2 file exists in the server and was able to reference it in the:

`<link rel="preload" href="fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>`.

As all I get from PageSpeed Insights is the content of the image below:

[image]

How do I solve this for the initial path?

Comment: try adding this file in footer with defer <link rel="preload" href="fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin defer> or <link rel="preload" href="fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin async>